# Re-scheduled Agent Job fails instantly without doing anything: previous schedules and manual runs work OK

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job

I have an Agent Job which executes SSIS packages. I created it last week, ran it and scheduled it for nightly runs. Both manual runs and scheduled runs worked without a hitch. Yesterday I scheduled the Agent Job to run at midnight (00:00:00). This morning I noticed that none of the packages inside the Agent Job had run. EventLog tells me that the Agent Job both started and failed at the exact same timestamp, 00:00:00, which doesn't make any sense. All my other Agent Jobs ran fine and I have no issues running the failed Agent Job manually.

I've ran identical Agent Jobs for months on this server and I have never encountered this behavior before. Where should I start troubleshooting? What could cause the Agent Job to just fail without even doing anything? Currently my only solution is delete the existing job and create a new one and hope it doesn't occur again.

**EDIT:**
*While the original issue was about having to deal with deadlocked processes, sometime ago I ran into another similar situation where I couldn't figure out why a new package kept crashing without a sensible reason. Turns out I set it to run on the wrong node (PROD when it should have been BETA) in the AgentJob step settings.*

Comment: Look in the history of the job for any error messages.

Comment: As @TabAlleman pointed out, check in the job history and make sure to drill down to the Step ID on which you are calling the job to look for error. At the high level the error would not precipitate

Comment: Good idea, and I don't know why it didn't cross my mind earlier. I had a similar crash again and found the error in the Agent Job history. ("Description: Transaction (Process ID 116) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim"). Thanks.